# How to customized API calls to Carriers in Acumatica

Tags: api, acumatica, fedex, ups, usps

I would like to customize the API calls to the carriers to add "Reference Fields" .. How is that possible with Acumatica?

Do we have the ability to gain access to the Carrier API Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to implement a custom Carrier plugin if you want to modify any aspect of an existing plugin unfortunately.

You can do this by creating an extension library that contains an object that inherits from the ICarrierService interface, and then implementing the necessary fields.

This object will then be available in the lookup under the carriers screen

[image: The plugin type lookup]